# SSAS Date Format

Tags: date, format, ssas, analysis, azure-analysis-services

Good Morning!

I'm trying to change the date format of employees dimension on AdventureWorks to PT-BR, but without success. Someone could help me? The format I want is 30/09/2019 (dd/MM/yyyy).

Date format:
[image: Date format Image:]

Region:
[image: Region Image:]

The data:
[image: The data Image:]
Thank you.